# Extract Shopify Data Via Web Activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, shopify

I need to get the Shopify Data via Web Activity in Azure Data Factory.

I can extract the data via Post Man without any issues. I used the same URL in Azure Data Factory, but it is throwing the error below:

> {"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}

The URL that works in Postman is
https://{{api_key}}:{{api_password}}@{{store_name}}.myshopify.com/admin/api/{{api_version}}/products.json?

I used the same URL in Web Activity in ADF.

[image]

Can you please tell me what could be the issue here?

Comment: https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/17056443-how-to-generate-a-shopify-api-token check if it helps you

Comment: Are you aware Datafactory has a connector for Shopify?

Comment: Yes, the connector works fine without filters. For example, if you add a filter to retrieve the orders created_at > yesterday's date, it takes too long to retrieve records.